# How to encrypt\decrypt files\images Fields in django?

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-rest-framework

I am trying to understand what is the best practice to encrypt a file\image using django drf.

In my app the user upload sensitive data which I later on store in the cloud.
The data contains files and images. I wish to encrypt the files in a way that even if someone hack the cloud the data is encrypt.

as a code exmaple

```
# models.py
class FilesHandler(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # -- File is save in the cloud, use djagno-storages -- #want to add encrypt feature
    my_file= models.FileField(storage=MediaStorage(), upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)
    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

After a long research I only found the [django-encrypted-filefield](https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-filefield/) repo which last commit was done about 2 years ago.In addition I found small amount of data on the topic (could not find even one code example beside the repo mention above).

Can someone share what is the best pratice to encrypt the data on the server side before sending to the cloud storage? a Django code example link would be *appreciated*

#### Update

In the mean time as a "between" solution, I put the following code in

```
# Serializers.py
def _encrypt(self, file):
    encrypted = self.aes.encrypt(file.read())
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    buffer.write(encrypted)
    return buffer
```

Comment: In the mean time as a "between" solution I put the following code in the 
```
# Serializers.py     
def _encrypt(self, file):
        encrypted = self.aes.encrypt(file.read())
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        buffer.write(encrypted)
        return buffer
```

Comment: please try this method: https://pyshark.com/encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-python/